# How to receive RealTime Instagram update using python-instagram?

Tags: python, flask, instagram

I just wanted to know how to receive `RealTime Update` the update from `python-instagram`

It's actually a Flask application and hosted in Google Cloud VM. So far so good. I can subscribe to the particular `tag` or `user`. And I think instagram post the update to my server.

```
173.252.105.114 - - [19/Oct/2015:01:40:52 -0400] "POST /hook/instagram HTTP/1.1" 301 517 "-" "Python-httplib2/0.8 (gzip)"
173.252.108.115 - - [19/Oct/2015:01:40:53 -0400] "POST /hook/instagram HTTP/1.1" 301 517 "-" "Python-httplib2/0.8 (gzip)"
173.252.108.119 - - [19/Oct/2015:01:41:31 -0400] "POST /hook/instagram HTTP/1.1" 301 517 "-" "Python-httplib2/0.8 (gzip)"
173.252.113.116 - - [19/Oct/2015:01:41:41 -0400] "POST /hook/instagram HTTP/1.1" 301 517 "-" "Python-httplib2/0.8 (gzip)"
```

So I guess using the reactor is best way to receive and I did something like this ....

```
""" Hook for real time update """
def process_tag_update(update):
    new = RealUpdate(update['subscription_id'], updata['object_id'], update['object'])
    db.session.add(new)
    db.session.commit()
    print 'Received a push: '

reactor = subscriptions.SubscriptionsReactor()
reactor.register_callback(subscriptions.SubscriptionType.TAG, process_tag_update)
```

Hook url handling ....

```
@app.route('/hook/instagram/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hook_instagram():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # POST event is used to for the events notifications
        x_hub_signature = request.headers.get('X-Hub-Signature')
        raw_response = request.data
        try:
            reactor.process(CLIENT_SECRET, raw_response, x_hub_signature)
        except subscriptions.SubscriptionVerifyError:
            print 'Signature mismatch'
        return 'done'
    else:
        hub_challenge =  request.args.get('hub.challenge')
        return '{}'.format(hub_challenge)
```

But I don't know is this the right way... I got blind what will come from `process_tag_update(update)` because ...

1. I can't able to print
2. i Can't able to debug

So Is anybody experiencing similar issue.. ? How to overcome this.? And also if you have any ideas to achieve please let me know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `301` redirect. You have to make sure your real time callback URL ends with `/`

Ex:- `/hook/instagram/`

Comment: I got a problem with instagram app nodejs, instagram keep sending 301 http code because the end of url is missing '/', by checking that I can reslove it now, thank you so much. Upvote.